# How to skip deleted records in codeigniter database query

Tags: php, codeigniter

In a project, I'm displaying recently viewed/searched shop name for customers to access it quickly. I have deleted few shops directly from the database. While displaying the recently searched shop details, I'm getting this php error message "Trying to get property of non-object". Have pasted the code below.

```
<?php if(user_logged_in()){ ?>
     <?php $recent = $this->db->select('user_id,shop_id')
                     ->where('user_id',get_session('userid'))
                     ->distinct('user_id')->distinct('shop_id')
                     ->get('recent_view')->result(); ?>
     <?php if(!empty($recent)){ ?>
           <div class="recent shop_list_area" >
                <span class="greypara grey">Recent search</span>

                <ul class="list-group">
                    <?php foreach($recent as $k): ?>
                    <?php $shop = $this->db->where('id',$k->shop_id)
                                  ->get('shop_list')->row(); ?>
                    <?php $idfe = $this->db->where('user_id',$k->user_id)
                                 ->where('shop_id',$shop->id)->get('feedback')->row(); ?>

                    <?php if(empty($idfe)){ ?>
                    <?php if(!empty($shop)){ ?>
```

Comment: Can you share the **exact** error message and mark the line throwing the error?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/search.php

Comment: Either your data is empty or you are not accessing correct column, that is why u got the error

Comment: all the query related code should be done in model that is why model are there

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access result of query directly first u need to check `num_rows()` of $recent if it is returning any rows num_rows() >0 then fetch result and also check your query is correct may be its returning an error and ur are accessing `result()` of string.

Comment: I'm new to Codeigniter, pardon my ignorance. Should I add this after the query?  return $recent->num_rows();

Comment: Yes check num_rows() in place of empty check and then access $data = $recent->result() inside if condition. You can check sql query by print query which fired in db by echo $this->db->last_query();

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your function

```
public function Your_Method(){
    $query = $this->db->select('user_id,shop_id')->where('user_id',get_session('userid'))->distinct('user_id, shop_id')->get('recent_view');
    $recent = ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : false;
    $this->load->view('Your_view_file', compact('recent'));
}
```

now `$recent` will return the result from the database, now check it before the call in the view file

```
if($recent && array_filter($recent)){
  // your code            
}else{
  echo 'empty result';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting this php error message "Trying to get property of
> non-object". Have pasted the code below.

***Cause***

`It's because some of your queries are empty.`

***What you're doing wrong are as follows :***

- `->get('recent_view')->result();`
- `->get('feedback')->row();`

Without making sure that, there were rows returned by your query, you are calling either `result()/row()`.

We cannot ensure that the query will always produce a result it depends on database table and query you made, suppose if your query returns no results then it cannot invoke either `row()` or `result()` method.

What you have to do is, chain all your methods till `get('your_table')` and assign it to some variable say `$query`, and then make sure you got some records

```
$query = $this->db->select('user_id,shop_id')
                  ->where('user_id',get_session('userid'))
                  ->distinct('user_id, shop_id')
                  ->get('recent_view');

if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){

     // here you call either $query -> result() ; $query->row();
     // depending on your requirement.

}else {

    // throw new Exception("No records found");

}
```